# Getting null pointer from java.sql.Date setter

Tags: java

I have problem with setting java.sql.Date field in my object.
I got the string from text field, parsed it to java.util.Date, and then created java.sql.Date object from it.
Object is not null, as it prints out, but when I pass it as a parameter to setter, I get null pointer exception.

```
dt = formatter.parse(forma.getTxtdatum().getText());
System.out.println(dt); //prints out correct date
Date datum = new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());
System.out.println(datum); //prints out correct date
clan.setDatum_rodjenja(datum); //throws null pointer exception
```

Any ideas would be usefull

Comment: Are you certain that `clan` is not `null`?

Comment: Please, post the source code from your class. Maybe you made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake when declaring variables, so one of them remained null and I tried to use that one

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `clan` variable is `null`.